# How to loop over all characters in a String array

Tags: java, arrays, string, testing, junit

I am working a Hash Table project. So I have an array which will hold the Strings. `ArrayList<String> buckets = new ArrayList<>();`

I want to create a method `hash` but I am stuck on how to make that method takes in a String and loops over the individual characters in that string and sums their number values all together, and then return the integer sum.

The method `hash` will use for the test below:

```
@Test
public void testToString() {
    HashTable h=   new HashTable(10);

    org.junit.Assert.assertEquals( "Empty hash output" ,
             "(0)\t\n"
            +"(1)\t\n"
            +"(2)\t\n"
            +"(3)\t\n"
            +"(4)\t\n"
            +"(5)\t\n"
            +"(6)\t\n"
            +"(7)\t\n"
            +"(8)\t\n"
            +"(9)\t\n"

            , h+""/*.toString()*/
            );
}

@Test
public void hashFunction() {
    HashTable h=   new HashTable(10);

    org.junit.Assert.assertEquals( "hash function test" , 
            4
            , h.hash("abc") % h.size()
            );
    org.junit.Assert.assertEquals( "hash function test backwards string" , 
            4
            , h.hash("cba") % h.size()
            );
```

Thank you in advances!

Comment: `for (char c : myString.toCharArray()) {//code }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing it - for example, you can use `charAt(i)` and a `for` loop:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i != s.length() ; i++) {
    sum += s.charAt(i);
}
```

You could also convert the string to an array of characters, and use it in a `for (char ch : s.toCharArray())` statement, but it would result in an additional memory allocation for the array of characters.

**Note 1:** you should watch out for numeric overflow.

**Note 2:** Consider using a different method for computing hash values. Adding up character codes would work, but strings with reordered characters would have identical hash codes.